# Unable to locate text in element protractor

Tags: xpath, protractor

I want to verify that some text is present on a page using protractor.

Attached is the page tag I want to verify and the text I want to verify is:

```
Vi har mottatt din melding. Vi ser på denne så snart som mulig,
normalt innen neste arbeidsdag.
```

Using xpath is not working as in:

```
var xpath = '//*[@id="app"]/div/section[2]/article/section[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]';

var txt = element(by.xpath(xpath)).getText();

expect(txt).toEqual(
    'Vi har mottatt din melding. Vi ser på denne så snart som mulig,' +
    ' normalt innen neste arbeidsdag.');
```

Any tips?

Comment: please share your `html` with stack trace.

Comment: tip: [NEVER use xpath](http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide)

Comment: If you have found a solution by your own or with answers below, please close choosing the answer (or post your one and chose that); If not, provide comments so someone else could help you

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;    
expect(EC.presenceOf(element(by.xpath('//span[text()='Vi har mottatt din melding. Vi ser på denne så snart som mulig, normalt innen neste arbeidsdag.']))));
```

the `//` tells xpath you are doing a relative path so that in english that command should expect the presence of a span containing the text you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

define async your function (or test) that has the getText() inside, then
try using async getText(), it returns a promise so:

`var txt = await element(by.xpath(xpath)).getText();`

for example, my test function is like:

```js
export async function getSelectOptionAutocompleteByText(select: ElementFinder, text: string): promise.Promise<ElementFinder> {
  let ret: any;
  const res = await select.all(by.cssContainingText('li', text));
  for (const el of res) {
    const ris = await el.getText(); // -----this is what i mean----
    if (ris === text) {
      ret = el;
      return ret;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```